# Flexbox-based grid goes 'out of bounds' in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

The following example works ok in Chrome in Firefox, showing a grid with evenly populated rows.

However, it fails in Safari. Some elements disappear (obviously due to the `overflow: hidden` rule in the container), as if the width of the container were ignored.

Why is that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
    .enlaces-home {
        width: 85%;
        max-width: 1600px;

        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;

            display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;

      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;

          flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .enlaces-home a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .enlace-home {
        display: block;
    }

    .enlaces-home > div {
        /*flex: 1 1 30%;*/
        min-width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px 5px;

        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .enlaces-home > div img {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        border: 3px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="enlaces-home">
<div><a href="">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/186" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </a></div>
<div><a href="">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/186" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </a></div>
<div><a href="">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/186" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </a></div>
<div><a href="">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/186" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </a></div>
<div><a href="">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/186" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </a></div>
<div><a href="">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/276/186" alt="">
        <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </a></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: I've tried with both Safari 7 and Safari 9 and the behavior is the same.